# Neo4JClient cannot retrieve Dictionary with values as objects

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

Need help with Neo4Client, if I run fluent cypher query and use
`.Return(node => node.As<Dictionary<string,string>>())` it returns both correct keys and values albeit with loss of a datatype, but if I use `.Return(node => node.As<Dictionary<string,object>>())` it returns dictionary with keys, but no values that I can see. The debugger shows {object}, but I cannot cast it to anything - the field that I know is a string returns null when casting - `obj as string`. Same happens with `Dictionary<<string, dynamic>>`. What is this object and how can I retrieve my dictionary back from Neo4j using client?

Comment: The problem is that when you do `.As<Dictionary<string, object>>` you are telling Neo4jClient to deserialize the values to objects - once you do that, you do not *have* strings, you just have objects. It might be worth seeing what you can do with `dynamic` but beyond that I would look at using a common type for your values (even if it is just a wrapper for properties of different types).

Comment: Sorry, markup didn't work first time. Dynamic casts to objects too. I can parse the strings, it's just super highly inefficient. Did you had something else for wrapper in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Writing up the result of a Gitter conversation, and discussion [here](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/issues/160).

So this is down to the way `Neo4jClient` deserializes objects back, specifically the `OGM` (**O**bject **G**raph **M**apping) side of things. Basically it treats `Dictionary<string, object>` in a *bespoke* way, which in the long run `Activates` a `new object` instance, hence the `object`s *actually* being `object` instances, and not a `string` or equivalent.

There's no way (at present) around this without changing the `OGM` side of things substantially.